# unable to edit /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward in Xubuntu

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu

I try to change `ip_forward` from `0` to `1` but fail, even with root permission in Xubuntu 11.10. I don't have such similar problem while using Ubuntu 11.10

```
chiaki@chiaki:~$ sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
```

any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can not re-direct so easily with `sudo`. There are several potential solutions, including `tee`.

You can re-direct to files you own as the user calling `sudo`, such as files in your home directory, but not system files.

Example

```
# it works when re-direction to a location / file the user has permission to access
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$sudo echo "it works" > ~/file
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$cat file
it works

# But NOT if you do not have permission to access the target
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$sudo echo "it works" > /root/file
-bash: /root/file: Permission denied
```

#### Option one

use `sudo bash -c` and quote the entire command

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

#### Option two

Use `tee`

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: This completely worked for me! Just a couple of extra questions though: i) can I make those changes somehow persist through reboots and ii) why do those two commands even work?! and iii) why can't I even change the permission or the owner of that file, even when logged in as root?

Comment: @George - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent . As to your other questions, best ask a question rather then ask in the comments. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change parameters in `/proc/sys`, the best thing to do is edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then run `sysctl -p`. That way your changes will persist across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
user@ubuntu:~sudo -s 
enter password for sudo:
root@ubuntu:~echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward :)
```

Comment: While this probably will solve the problem, it would certainly be useful to know why this works in contrast to the use of `sudo` in the question. Namely, while `echo` will be run with superuser permissions, the output redirecton `>` will still run with the current shells permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the following command, it will works if you don't reboot your computer.

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

once rebooted, the parameter will back to "0"

Try the following command, and it will work even after you reboot.

```
vim /proc/sysctrl.conf ' - uncommen "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"

sysctl -p
```

now, even, when you reboot your machine, IP forwarding will be always enabled.