# How to make IP forwarding permanent?

Tags: routing

I know that I can enable IP forward by echoing `1` to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, but how can I make this permanent?

By the way I want another method rather than start up scripts, is there any?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf and search for the following lines:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Or in one line command :

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` doesn't make it permanent... @ least on a raspberry pi I tested...

Comment: do you need to reboot too? or is there a way to "live" apply it too

Comment: @user230910 No need to reboot if using `sudo sysctl -w ...`

Comment: `-w` immediately enables the setting. It does not make it persistent though!

Answer (score 24):

Permanent setting using `/etc/sysctl.conf`

If we want to make this configuration permanent the best way to do it is using the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` where we can add a line containing `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

```
/etc/sysctl.conf:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

If you already have an entry `net.ipv4.ip_forward` with the value 0 you can change that to 1.

To enable the changes made in `sysctl.conf` you will need to run the command:

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

On RedHat based systems this is also enabled when restarting the network service:

```
service network restart
```

and on Debian/Ubuntu systems this can be also done restarting the procps service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/procps restart
```

Source: [How to Enable IP Forwarding in Linux](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to enable it in script you can use commands below to enable

```
sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

or disable:

```
sed -i 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=0/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in the command line to enable: the idea is changing the value 0 for 1 so it should be:
`ed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=0/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p`

Comment: No. Enabling command just remove "#" in the beginning. So there is no typo

Comment: [ilya](https://askubuntu.com/users/1096080/ilya), you are correct, I will take back my comment. I missed that the target was to remove the # alone. Instead, I thought of matching an uncommented line with the disabled setting of 0 to change it to the enabled value of 1.

Comment: @ilya yes but disabling them should add back the "#" and not putting value 0, since if you have to reenable again it will not do it...