# ip_forward wont stay enabled after reboot

Tags: networking

Using Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS

I've changed `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to 1 in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and when I run `sudo sysctl -p` it works no problem but after a reboot `ip_forward` is back to 0.

After a reboot I can run `sudo sysctl -p` again and it works

How can I make it persist?

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` is correct way to keep forwarding across reboots. I suggest to look into `/etc/sysctl.d/*` files if there is an override to 0 somewhere.

Comment: None of the files contain an override and I've tried adding another file to this folder with an override to 1 and its still not persisting

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be some problem with AWS VPN Client where the client turns ip forwarding off:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=345484

For most people who land here this won't be the problem.  But it might help a few people.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent)  and review the steps you made to set port forwarding on Linux.

Comment: Found that answer when I was looking into the problem before asking this question.

It loads the config no problem but it doesn't persist between reboots