# Ubuntu 16.04 not dynamically assigning an ip address to enp5s0

Tags: networking

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04

When i connect another computer or Gigabit switch through the wired connection it fails to assign an ip address to enp5s0.

I understand i could configure a static ip but i would prefer to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's unclear who you connect to whom.

Comment: On older distributions  when i connect another computer direct to my computer, my computer would assign an ip address to the connection eth0 now changed to enp5s0.

Comment: you need to enable IP forwarding. Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent#311054

Comment: On a direct computer-to-computer connection, there's no DHCP server, so you must assign static IP addresses. When connected to a switch, is there also a router/modem attached to the same switch. If not, same problem. If so, make sure your `Wired Connection` profile is set to use DHCP. Cheers, Al

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your help, however i've made the following progress.

I ran this command to check the model number of my Ethernet Controller

```
lspci | grep Realtek
```

The output

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

I then checked checked what driver the kernel was loading

```
lsmod | grep r816*
```

The output

```
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
```

Seeing that they did not match i headed over to the Realtek website to get the RTL8101 Driver but they only have it for the 3.x, 2.6.x and 2.4.x kernels.

And so either I have to wait until Realtek release a driver for kernel 4.x or upgrade my hardware.

spacelander thanks for the link i learned from it

heynnema i assure you that you can connect direct and get an ip number, as I've been doing it for years and I'm sure with the correct driver I'll do it again.

Thanks & Regards 
Jonny

Comment: The `r8169` kernel module is supposed to support your card. I do not think the problem is with the module. Anyway you do not have to "wait". You can install the Realtek driver from Ubuntu repos. It is `r8168-dkms` package.

Comment: Pilot 6, I installed the r8168-dkms but r8169 still remains in lsmod am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You did something wrong. `r8168` blacklists `r8169`. What does `dkms status` show and `sudo modprobe r8168`?

Comment: dkms status  r8168, 8.041.00, 4.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed   modprobe r8168 no output. Thanks

Comment: Oops. I did not read the question carefully. You can remove it. It is not for your card. Your card is supported by in-tree r8169.

Comment: Pilot 6, I have limited experience but i get the feeling this is a kernel issue ever since the time eth0 changed to enp5s0 there has been problems. I don't know if they would even consider this an issue but it affects guys like me thanks for all your help.