# Ping loopback from another computer

Tags: networking, ping, routing, loop-device

I'm having trouble setting up static routing.
My target machine `192.168.1.36` has a loopback address of `192.168.46.1` `255.255.255.255` which I am trying to ping from another device in the network `192.168.1.28`.

On `192.168.1.36` I can ping the loopback and the source machine.

From the source machine `192.168.1.28` I have added the following static route:

```
route add -net 192.168.46.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.36 dev ens3
```

However I cannot ping `192.168.46.1` despite being able to ping `192.168.1.36`.

There are no firewall rules in place blocking ICMP.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable ip forwarding?  See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent

Comment: Hi, yes ip forwarding is definitely enabled.

Comment: [The route command is deprecated, and should not be used anymore.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292834/routing-to-the-localhost-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 1):

In `Linux` a loopback adapter is valid only inside of its owner. You can't `ping` or communicate it from remote devices (You can remote access to loopback on Cisco devices)

Comment: Ah right didn't know that (my background is Cisco). However I created the loopback as I was having issues pinging a VM 192.168.56.1 and created the loopback to see if I could prove the issue to the static routes or the VM. Again I can ping the VM from its host 192.168.1.32 but not from another device on the 192.168.1.0 subnet

Comment: You can use bridge port in VMware configuration of your virtual machine to enable pining of it from any other devices in your network.

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox with a Host only adapter, I'm running cuckoo sandbox which is a bit of a nightmare to configure so don't want to start messing with the network settings of the VM. I find it weird that the host can ping the guest VM bit no other device can.

Comment: using NAT adapter and adding static route to other devices may solve the problem. There is an bug in Windows version of VBox which you can't ping Guest from Host when using NAT interface. I don't know this problem exists with Linux too.